# VBAScript to delete items from folder

Tags: vbscript, automation

I'm new to VBScripting and have completely no knowledge on how to code but however i understand the basics of VBScripting.

I tried using the search function to find similar cases to mine but it doesn't have what i need.

I would really appreciate any help as my project is due soon.

Scenario:

I need to delete jpeg files that are more than 3months old that is in a directory with lots and lots of subfolders within each other. Furthermore there are 4 folders in the directory that i must not delete or modify.

How i manually did it was to navigate to the mapped drive, to the folder, use the "Search 'Folder'" from the window and type in this "datemodified:‎2006-‎01-‎01 .. ‎2013-‎08-‎31".

It will then show all the folders and subfolders and excel sheets within that folder, i'll then filter the shown list by ticking jpeg only from Type.

Code:
'************ Start of Code **********************

```
 Option Explicit 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Dim oFSO, oFolder, sDirectoryPath 
 Dim oFileCollection, oFile, sDir 
 Dim iDaysOld
```

' Specify Directory Path From Where You want to clear the old files

```
 sDirectoryPath = "C:\MyFolder"
```

' Specify Number of Days Old File to Delete

```
 iDaysOld = 15

 Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
 Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sDirectoryPath) 
 Set oFileCollection = oFolder.Files 

For each oFile in oFileCollection
```

'This section will filter the log file as I have used for for test case 
'Specify the Extension of file that you want to delete 
'and the number with Number of character in the file extension

```
If LCase(Right(Cstr(oFile.Name), 4)) = "jpeg" Then

    If oFile.DateLastModified < (Date() - iDaysOld) Then 
    oFile.Delete(True) 
    End If 

End If   
Next 

Set oFSO = Nothing 
enter code here`Set oFolder = Nothing 
enter code here`Set oFileCollection = Nothing 
enter code here`Set oFile = Nothing
```

'*************** End of Code ******************

I need to set an path that must be excluded + go through sub folders.

I'd like to thank you in advance for helping me out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution (Jobbo almost got it to work in generic form):

**UPDATE: includes log file writing with number of folders skipped and files deleted.**

```
Option Explicit

'set these constants to your requirements
Const DIR = "C:\Test"
Const LOGFILE = "C:\Log.txt" ' Location of Log file
Const MAX_AGE = 3 ' Unit: Months
Const FILEEXT = "jpeg"

Dim oFSO
Dim oLogFile
Dim aExclude
Dim lngDeletes, lngSkips

'add to this array to exclude paths
aExclude = Array("c:\Test\test 1", "c:\Test\test 2\test")

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set oLogFile = oFSO.createtextfile(LOGFILE)
lngDeletes = 0
lngSkips = 0
LOGG "Script Start time: " & Now
LOGG "Root Folder: " & DIR
LOGG String(50, "-")

deleteFiles oFSO.GetFolder(DIR)

LOGG String(50, "-")
LOGG lngDeletes & " files are deleted"
LOGG lngSkips & " folders skipped"
LOGG "Script End time: " & Now
oLogFile.Close
Set oLogFile = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing
MsgBox "Logfile: """ & LOGFILE & """", vbInformation, wscript.scriptName & " Completed at " & Now
wscript.Quit

'=================================
Sub LOGG(sText)
    oLogFile.writeline sText
End Sub
'=================================
Function isExclude(sPath)
    Dim s, bAns
    bAns = False
    For Each s In aExclude
        If InStr(1, sPath, s, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            bAns = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    isExclude = bAns
End Function
'=================================
Function isOldFile(fFile)
    ' Old file if "MAX_AGE" months before today is greater than the file modification time
    isOldFile = (DateAdd("m", -MAX_AGE, Date) > fFile.DateLastModified)
End Function
'==================================
Function isFileJPEG(fFile)
    Dim sFileName
    sFileName = fFile.Name
    ' Mid(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, ".")) gives you the extension with the "."
    isFileJPEG = (LCase(Mid(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, ".") + 1)) = FILEEXT)
End Function
'==================================
Sub deleteFiles(fFolder)
    Dim fFile, fSubFolder
    If Not isExclude(fFolder.Path) Then
        'WScript.echo "==>> """ & fFolder.Path & """" ' Comment for no output
        For Each fFile In fFolder.Files
            If isFileJPEG(fFile) And isOldFile(fFile) Then
                lngDeletes = lngDeletes + 1
                LOGG lngDeletes & vbTab & fFile.Path
                'WScript.echo vbTab & "DELETE: """ & fFile.Path & """" ' Comment for no output
                fFile.Delete True ' Uncomment to really delete the file
            End If
        Next
        ' Only Process sub folders if current folder is not excluded
        For Each fSubFolder In fFolder.SubFolders
            deleteFiles fSubFolder
        Next
    Else
        lngSkips = lngSkips + 1
        'WScript.echo "<<-- """ & fFolder.Path & """" ' Comment for no output
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The code seems promising but however i get an error when i try to run the code. It says something like WScript.Quit is not defined. The same goes with the other WScripts. when i tried editing the code myself.

Comment: what operating system and version you have? did you run it in command prompt with `cscript`? Remove the line `Option Explicit` and have another go.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The script is working absolutely fine. I decided to comment on all WScript.Echo as there are probably 40k folders total, can't have 40k pop ups happening. However i do need one more line of code to say that the script has finished running can you help me with that? Thanks a lot Patrick :)

PS, is it possible to let the script record whatever that was deleted in a notepad/excel sheet?

Comment: @user2977612 you could have used cscript in command prompt and redirect the wscript.echo to a text file. but have updated the code to log deletes and simple summary at end to a log file.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever use `On Error Resume Next` unless it absolutely cannot be avoided.

This problem needs a recursive function. Here's how I would do it:

```
Option Explicit

'set these constants to your requirements
Const DIR = "C:\MyFolder"
Const AGE = 15

Dim oFSO
Dim aExclude

'add to this array to exclude paths
aExclude = Array("c:\folder\exclude1", "c:\folder\another\exclude2")

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Call deleteFiles(oFSO.GetFolder(DIR))

Set oFSO = Nothing
WScript.Quit

'=================================
Function isExclude(sPath)
  Dim s

  For Each s in aExclude
    If LCase(s) = LCase(sPath) Then
      isExclude = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  isExclude = False
End Function

'==================================
Sub deleteFiles(fFolder)
  Dim fFile, fSubFolder

  If Not isExclude(fFolder.Path) Then
    For Each fFile in fFolder.Files
      If (LCase(Right(Cstr(fFile.Name),4)) = "jpeg") And (fFile.DateLastModified < (Date() - AGE)) Then
        'WScript.echo fFile.Path 'I put this in for testing, uncomment to do the same
        Call fFile.Delete(true)
      End If
    Next
  End If
  For Each fSubFolder in fFolder.SubFolders
    Call deleteFiles(fSubFolder)
  Next
End Sub
```

I'm not really able to fully test it out because I don't have an example data set, but really all you need to do is set `DIR` and change the `aExclude` array. Make sure you know what its going to delete before you run it though...

Also, it will only delete `jpeg` extensions, not `jpg` but I imagine you already know that

Comment: Thanks for the code, everything is working fine but only the exclusion path. It still deletes items that are in the exclusion path. PS there are subfolders within the exclusion folders too.

Comment: I edited the code. The path matching appeared to be case sensitive so I added calls to `LCase` within `isExclude`. It will not delete files in the excluded folders but it **will** go into, and delete from, subfolders of excluded folders

Comment: If subfolders and files within the exclusions are not to to "touched", just change the If condition in `Function isExclude(sPath)` from Jobbo's answer. From `If LCase(s) = LCase(sPath) Then` to `If Instr(1,s,sPath,1) = 1 Then`. Refer [InStr description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c(v=vs.84).aspx). Then move the `For Each fSubFolder` loop just above the `End If. This will ensure only files and folders not in exclusion will be processed.

Comment: @PatricK Sorry for the really late reply, was on a long leave. I tried the new code + your edits but however it is not working. Turns out that i'm actually deleting files from the Excluded folders and not the planned one.